# Parse bs4 table from Baseball reference

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/NYN/NYN201704030.shtml'

def make_soup(url): 
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

soup = make_soup(url)
```

I'm trying to locate the play by play table on that page and I've exhausted every option.  Any thoughts on how to locate?

This is the *tbody* located under div.table_outer_container.mobile_table

Comment: The table is loaded via JS. You need to use other tools like selenium to access that table

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) in combination with BeautifulSoup to scrape that table content as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/NYN/NYN201704030.shtml")

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

pbp_table = soup.find_all("table", {"id":"play_by_play"})

for tag in pbp_table:
    print (tag.text)
```

If you want to use this code be sure to look at the [Selenium guide on drivers](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers) and download the latest [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) if you're using Firefox as in that code above.

Answer (score 0):

It is commented out in the source:

[image]

Look for the something to identify the comment, i.e the `play_by_play` id

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


cont = get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/NYN/NYN201704030.shtml").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(cont, "lxml")

# Search Comments
comment = soup.find(text=lambda n: isinstance(n, Comment) and 'id="play_by_play"' in n)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(comment)
table = soup2.select("#play_by_play")[0]
```

Which gets what you want:

```
In [3]: from requests import get
   ...: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
   ...: cont = get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/NYN/NYN201704030.sh
   ...: tml").content
   ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(cont, "lxml")
   ...: comment = soup.find(text=lambda n: isinstance(n, Comment) and 'id="pla
   ...: y_by_play"' in n)
   ...: soup2 = BeautifulSoup(comment, "lxml")
   ...: table = soup2.select("#play_by_play")[0]
   ...: print(table.select_one(".pbp_summary_top").text)
   ...: 
Top of the 1st, Braves Batting, Tied 0-0, Mets' Noah Syndergaard facing 1-2-3 

In [4]:
```

You can also use a regex with `text=...`:

```
cont = get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/NYN/NYN201704030.shtml").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(cont, "lxml")
comment = soup.find(text=compile('id="play_by_play"'))
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(comment, "lxml")
table = soup2.select("#play_by_play")[0]
```